# `M-x list-packages` not showing available packages

Tags: emacs

`M-x list-packages` is not showing available packages from Melpa and Marmalade. It is only showing built-in and installed packages.

It was working before. I am running emacs-26.3 on Debian Buster.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Emacs and running `M-x package-refresh-contents`? Usually Melpa or Marmalade packages should appear after refreshing the package lists

Comment: What, in your init file, do you have, that tells `list-packages` to include Melpa and Marmalade?

Comment: I also ran package-refresh-contents and restarted.I have this in init file. (let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
  (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
      (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make sure that your lines have `t` at the end.
`(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)` <-- notice `t`.
I see that your melpa does, but marmalade does not.
I was having a similar issue (lsp-mode wasn't showing up) and I noticed I was missing a `t` at end. Wrote it in then ran `M-x package-refresh-contents` and it worked.